# Container on same network not communicating with each other

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I have a mongodb container which i name e-learning
and i have a docker image which should connect to the mongodb container to update my database but it's not working  i get this error:
Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }

here's my docker build file

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1 
FROM golang:1.18 
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/worker 
COPY go.mod go.sum main.go  ./ 
RUN go mod download 
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app . 
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4-alpine   

FROM alpine:latest 
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates 
WORKDIR /root/ 
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib 
COPY --from=jrottenberg/ffmpeg / / 
COPY app.env /root 
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/worker/app . 
CMD ["./app"]
```

my docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  worker:
    image: worker
    environment:
     - MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/"
     - MONGO_DATABASE=e-learning 
     - RABBITMQ_URI=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq:5672/
     - RABBITMQ_QUEUE=upload
    networks:
     - app_network
    external_links:
     - e-learning
     - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - worker:/go/src/github.com/worker:rw

networks:
 app_network:
  external: true
volumes:
  worker:
```

my docker inspect network

```
[
    {
        "Name": "app_network",
        "Id": "f688edf02a194fd3b8a2a66076f834a23fa26cead20e163cde71ef32fc1ab598",
        "Created": "2022-06-27T12:18:00.283531947+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2907482267e1f6e42544e5e8d852c0aac109ec523c6461e003572963e299e9b0": {
                "Name": "rabbitmq",
                "EndpointID": "4b46e091e4d5a79782185dce12cb2b3d79131b92d2179ea294a639fe82a1e79a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8afd004a981715b8088af53658812215357e156ede03905fe8fdbe4170e8b13f": {
                "Name": "e-learning",
                "EndpointID": "1c12d592a0ef6866d92e9989f2e5bc3d143602fc1e7ad3d980efffcb87b7e076",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ad026f7e10c9c1c41071929239363031ff72ad1b9c6765ef5c977da76f24ea31": {
                "Name": "video-transformation-worker-1",
                "EndpointID": "ce3547014a6856725b6e815181a2c3383d307ae7cf7132e125c58423f335b73f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Your Compose setup doesn't seem to include a MongoDB container.  But in Docker 127.0.0.1 is usually "the current container", not another container on the same network.  You'll need a different host name to contact the other container, typically its Compose service name; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added extra hosts and changed my mongo uri to `host.docker.internal`
and it solved my problems

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  worker:
    image: worker
    environment:
     - MONGO_URI="mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/"
     - MONGO_DATABASE=e-learning 
     - RABBITMQ_URI=amqp://user:password@rabbitmq:5672/
     - RABBITMQ_QUEUE=upload
    networks:
     - app_network
    external_links:
     - e-learning
     - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - worker:/go/src/github.com/worker:rw
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

networks:
 app_network:
  external: true
volumes:
  worker:
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/"` to `MONGO_URI="mongodb://e-learning:27017/"` (working on the assumption that `e-learning` is the mongo container).

Within a container attached to a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) (the default) localhost (127.0.0.1) is the container itself. So your app container is trying to access the database at port `27017` on itself (not on the host or on the db container). The easiest solution is to use the [automatic DNS resolution between containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) that docker provides.